# Difference between 辺り and 周り

Tags: word-choice, usage, nuances

My kanji study book lists:

辺り【あたり】  as "surroundings, neighborhood"

周り【まわり】 as "neighborhood, around"

I looked the words up in a few dictionaries, but I'm having a hard time parsing the difference and usage of each.  Could someone explain or give some examples?

Comment: Be aware that 辺り can also be read as 「ほと・り」.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

辺り refers to geographically nearby places (usually within a few meters to a few hundred meters). Aの辺り includes both A and nearby places.

周り means "surrounding region/part/place" or "peripheral region". Aの周り refers to A's surrounding areas, which does not include A itself. It can be used with very large and small things.

[image]

Examples:

- ディズニーランドの辺り around Disney Land; Disney Land and/or its surrounding areas
- ディズニーランドの周り areas surrounding Disney Land (does not include Disney Land itself)
- 辺りは森だ。 (tends to be used when you're in the middle of a forest)
- 周りは森だ。 (tends to be used when you're in a comfortable building/town which is surrounded by a forest)
- 地球は太陽の周りを回転している。
  The earth revolves around the sun.

Comment: @istrasci ありがとうございます m(_ _)m

Comment: ニュアンス微妙ですね!!!!!

Comment: That's perfect - just the clarification I needed.  It also ties into my association of 周 with circumference.