# How to say, "Where is the best izakaya close by to here?"

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese

I am interested in learning how to say, colloquially, "Where is the best Izakaya around here?"  Or "Where is the best Izakaya close to here?"

How far off am I with this translation below:

> ここのいちばんの居酒屋はどこですか。

Comment: It also depends what you mean by "best".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your attempt is good, but you need to use この辺り【あたり】の instead of ここの to say "*around* here".

> この辺りのいちばんの居酒屋はどこですか。

Related: [Difference between 辺り and 周り](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57266/5010)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use (ここの近ちかく) Meaning close to here/this locationここの近ちかくに居酒屋はどこですか。

Comment: Unfortunately this sentence has two errors. 1) "近ちかく" is not a valid word. Please check the spelling. 2) You have to use の to modify 居酒屋 because it's a noun.

Comment: I wonder if answer OP meant to do 近｛ちか｝く

Answer (score 1):

It is better to say `delicious` explicitly.

> この辺りでいちばんおいしい居酒屋はどこですか。